# calculating result of a function for a column of a dataframe in python

Tags: python, function, pandas, dataframe

I am working on a dataframe in python to calculate the distance between a location and `LATITUDE` and `LONGITUDE` column in the dataframe.  When I run the code below, there is no error:

```
lLat= 43.679194
lLon= -79.633352
LCentroid= (lLat, lLon)
# getDistanceBetween gets two centroids and calculate the distance
dfTowers['distance']= HL.getDistanceBetween(LCentroid, dfTowers.index.get_level_values('LATITUDE')[0],     dfTowers.index.get_level_values('LONGITUDE')[0]))
```

but when I use the below one, there is an error

```
lLat= 43.679194
lLon= -79.633352
LCentroid= (lLat, lLon)

dfTowers['distance']= HL.getDistanceBetween(LCentroid, dfTowers.index.get_level_values('LATITUDE'), dfTowers.index.get_level_values('LONGITUDE')))
```

and the error is:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-43-065640ee0e20> in <module>()
  5 
  6 dfTowers['distance']= HL.getDistanceBetween(LCentroid,     (dfTowers.index.get_level_values('LATITUDE'), 
----> 7                                         dfTowers.index.get_level_values('LONGITUDE')))

C:\Users\x190523\Documents\python exercice\HomeLocation.pyc in getDistanceBetween(c1, c2)

TypeError: a float is required
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because [`get_level_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_level_values.html) return a "vector" of labels. In your first example, you access the vector and appropriately retrieve the value. In your second example, you pass the entire vector and `getDistanceBetween` doesn't know what to do with it.

Edit:
Now to compute it for all rows, we don't need any of the syntax fr above

```
# add the new column, initialized to NaN
dfTowers['distance'] = np.nan
for row_name, row in dfTowers.iterrows():
    row['distance'] = HL.getDistanceBetween(LCentroid, row['LATITUDE'], row['LONGITUDE'])
```

Comment: so, how can I resolve the problem. note: `dfTowers` is generated using `group by`.

Comment: I thought if you just use the code in your first example, everything will work. You were able to verify yourself the first example worked. Can you show us more of what you are working with?

Comment: in the first example, the value of `distance` column is calculated using `latitude` and `longitude` of the first row. But I want to calculate the `distance` of each row based on the value of `latitude` and `longitude` of the corresponding row. I guess if I can access the result of a dataframe created using group by similar to a simple dataframe, the problem will be solved. But, I do not know how.

Comment: @user3854325 I have an update. Let me know if there are issues, I'm submitting from my phone.

Comment: thanks. it calculate the distance correctly, when I add another line of `print row ['distance']`, but it does not update the value in `dfTowers` and if I change ` row['distance']` with ` dfTowers['distance']`, it shows the last distance for all rows.

Comment: the problem is solved using `dfTowers.at [row_name, 'distance']` instead of `row['distance']`